# SQL Query (and NSPredicate) Help: Minimum Value with Group By

Tags: sql, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

This is probably a very beginner sql statement, but i'm having difficulties for some reason getting a query written for this simple table:

```
id  name    value
1   Felix   1
2   Bob     2
3   Charles 3
4   Mike    4
5   John    4
6   Peter   2
7   Felix   2
8   Felix   3
```

Here is a simple table. I want to group by name, with each group having a minimum value. For example the query should return:

```
1 Felix 1
2 Bob 2
3 Charles 3
4 Mike 4
5 John 4 
6 Peter 2
```

I tried:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP BY name HAVING min(value);`

but it doesn't work.

Bonus points if you can give me an NSPredicate in CoreData that would accomplish this as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: sqlite, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select min(ID), Name, min(value)
From yourtable
Group by  name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a subquery and a `JOIN`. The subquery gets the `min(value)` for each `name` and then you join that back to your table:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.value
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select name, min(value) MinVal
  from yourtable
  group by name
) t2
  on t1.name = t2.name
  and t1.value = t2.minval
order by t1.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6f04/4)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an NSFetchRequest version

```c
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Table"];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"value"];
NSExpression* expr = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"min:" arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"value"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:expr];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];
[request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"name"]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"name",expressionDescription]];
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* rez = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```